# Remove defect of display in ListDensityPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

I have a 3D volumetric data (for example, $64\times 64\times 64$, at each point there is a value) read in from a file and I want to use `ListDensityPlot3D` to generate a smooth plot. However, there is always a little hollow core in the blue spheres shown in the picture. If I simply flip the sign of the data value at all points, the defects again only exist in the blue spheres(local minimum of the data), which means the defect isn't caused by any discontinuity of the data.

Why does this happen and how could I get rid of it.

```
Plot1 = ListDensityPlot3D[Data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"} , 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All, All, All},
  ImageSize -> 500, Axes -> None, Boxed -> True, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]], 
  ViewPoint -> {1.3, -2.4, 2}, 
  OpacityFunction -> Interval[{-1, -0.5}, {0.5, 1}], 
  OpacityFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

Here is a link to an example data:
http://www.filedropper.com/out_13

The data is sorted in 1D. Here is the way to load it and transfer it to a table

```
Nx = 64;
Ny = 64;
Nz = 64;
a = Import["out.dat"];
b = Flatten[a];
Data = Table[
   b[[(z*Ny + y)*Nx + x + 1]], {z, 0, Nz - 1, 1}, {y, 0, Ny - 1, 
    1}, {x, 0, Nx - 1, 1}];
```

Comment: Please share your data as well

Comment: `OpacityFunction -> Interval[...]`  Are you sure that the data doesn't exceed that interval?

Comment: The data is between -1 and 1. Normally within a narrower window. But the problem still exists if I don't specify ```OpacityFunction```.

Comment: Yes. A link to a sample set of data is added in the question